# update a table which in not devise model on sign up using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How to add value from devise registration form to another table that is not devise table

this is sample code

```
<div class="signin">
  <h2>Register</h2>
  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

      <div><%= f.label :full_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :full_name %></div>


    <div><%= f.submit "Register" %></div>
  <% end %>

  <%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
```

full name is field of profile table and i set device on user table, 
and if user enter name i want name full name store in profile table
i dont have any idea how can i do this?

Comment: I don't want to add another controller to overrite devise method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer 
Put a def in devise model def name same as field name then devise allow you to pass the that field to model, in model/controller you can insert value through params in any table.

Answer (score 0):

you can use one of the many hooks that are provided by active record models:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#creating-an-object

ie. you could retrieve the profile object of the user, update the record and save it back in an `before_save` hook.