# how to modify new fields in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I added two fields to my devise user. I did this by adding them at the migrate file like this:

```
t.datetime  :access_bought_at, :default => DateTime.civil(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
t.string    :access_type, :default => "none"
```

and then making those attributes accessible at the user model:

```
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :access_type, :access_bought_at
```

Then made the migration (rake db:migrate).

But I'm having trouble accessing these fields and modifying them. I'm pretty new to rails, and I'm pretty sure the answer is pretty straightforward, but I cannot find (or understand what I find) about how to access and modify those field. This is what I'm trying to do. In certain controller I want to modify those fields, and I'm doing:

```
current_user::access_type = "forever"
current_user::access_bought_at = Date.current()
```

but then, if I make

```
puts current_user::email
puts current_user::access_type
puts current_user::access_bought_at
```

only the email get's printed out. I'm guessing that I'm missing either missing a step and I'm not updating the database, or I'm doing it just plain wrong. I read here ( [update a table which in not devise model on sign up using devise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719051/update-a-table-which-in-not-devise-model-on-sign-up-using-devise)) that I should just put a def in the model. A def how? It makes sense that since I change the model I should give instructions about how to modify it, so adding a method to do that seems right, but what should that method do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

devise user model still have activerecord api like any other model

```
current_user.access_type = "forever"
current_user.access_bought_at = Date.current()
current_user.save

puts current_user.email
puts current_user.access_type
puts current_user.access_bought_at
```